# getElementById works in IE browser but not in iFrame

Tags: javascript, java, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe

We have requirement to open Java application in Iframe in ASP.NET MVC application.

java struts render the HTML as follow (renders name attribute and not id attribute)

```
<input type="hidden" name="operation" value="">
```

java script method call

```
function submitForCheck(value)
{

  document.getElementById('operation').value = value;
  document.clientRateGroupForm.action = "CheckRGroup.do";
  document.clientRateGroupForm.submit();
}
```

if page is open in IE and click on check button it works and submit the form
If same page is open in iFrame and click on check button, nothing works. 
It fails at javascript line

```
document.getElementById('operation').value = value;
```

Any idea why it works directly in IE and not in iFrame.

Any suggestions to make it work in iFrame.

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"
    src="java application url"
    style="border: 0; width:1250px; height:800px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: It's `getElementById` and not `getElementByName`

Comment: any errors in browser console?

Comment: Its getElementById in java script, and it set the value for "operation" hidden input tag properly in IE browser, but it does not work in iFrame.

Comment: Exactly. Then why you're using it with a name and not an id?

Comment: Is the JS within the iframe as well, or is the parent window trying to access the element within the iframe?  If the latter, simple document.getElementById won't work because it's not accessing the iframe document...

Comment: Java application being called within iFrame is third party app. We don't have any control on it. When contacted their customer support they asked to run the application directly in browser and it works, so there is no actual issue with the app.